# Android Webview : know url redirection

Tags: redirect, android-webview

Is there any method to know whether the url being loaded in the webview is either `redirecting` to any other page or not ?

`E.g`

```
  I have an Edittext where I search for "car" .Now , result page for "car" is 
 loaded in the webview below. In the result page , I click for wikipedia link.
 There, First url loaded is "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automobile" which 
  automatically gets redirected to "https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automobile".
 I want to know this redirection.

Actually , I want to find whether the url loaded in webview is redirecting or not.
 If it's redirecting ,then,I want to capture it and take some actions.
```

Thank you in advance.Any help would be great.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, look at [WebViewClient.onPageStarted()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageStarted%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String,%20android.graphics.Bitmap%29). When called (upon each redirection) you can get the url via the `WebView` view parameter: view.`getUrl()`.

Comment: how would you differentiate if it's a redirected url or not ? view.getUrl() gives the url loaded in the webview.